# sed replace line with capture groups

Tags: sed

Is it possible with sed to replace a line with capture groups from the regex?

I have this regex, please note that this is fixed, I cannot change it.

`simple sample(.*)`

This is what I want:

```
This is just a simple sample line with some text
```

Change to:

```
line with some text
```

I need something like this:

```
sed '/simple sample \(.*\)/c \1'
```

Which now outputs:

```
1
```

Anybody knows if you can use capture groups in sed with the change line function?

Comment: You almost have it, you just need the `sed 's/find/replace/` syntax: `sed 's/\(.*\)simple sample \(.*\) with \(.*\)/\1\2/' file`. I don't know why you are using `\c` by the way.

Comment: Yes, I know it is possible for this example, thanks. But the problem is that I need to replace the line, because I have regexes that I need to process that when they match the line, I only have the replacement value available. Ie. I might have a regex `simple sample` that if it matches should change the line to `great`. When I use you're method I would get `This is just a great line with some text`. I know this could be solved when the correct regexes would be put into place (in this case `(.*)simple sample(.*)`, but this is not possible due the the amount I have. I'm limited to `/c`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I changed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

```
echo "This is just a simple sample line with some text" | \
  sed 's/simple sample \(.*\)/\n\1/;s/.*\n//'
```

The idea is simple: replace the whole regexp match with the captured group **preceded** by a newline. Then replace everything up to and including the first newline with nothing. Of course, you could use a marker other than the newline.

Comment: Yeah :-). Could you explain a bit what is happening in the last section?

Comment: Ah I understand. Wonderful, didn't know about the ;. For people finding this, the part before the ; puts what we need on a new line and the part after the ; removes the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'if (/(.*)simple sample (.*) with (.*)/) {
            print "$1$2\n";
          } else { print }'
```

Comment: Yeah that works, but I really need sed here, except when it is impossible.